# Change mysql DB design?

Tags: mysql

Alright. Lately I have been having some issues with do simpel coding for my little site. For the moment i have this DB design.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `hashtag` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` INT(11),
  `post_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `hashtag` VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY(post_id_fk) REFERENCES posts(post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And as you can see i have to union and join tables to get information and a lot of struggle with foreign keys.

Would it be favorably to change the DB design to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` INT(11),
  `comment_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `hashtag` VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY(comment_id_fk) REFERENCES (comment_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

So a comment can act as a "post", as well as a comment. If its possible to leave the foreign key blank. Or the foreign key maybe isn't even necessary?

Is this the way to go? Or should i continue with two tables?

Comment: Your foreign key column can be defined as `default null`. `null` is allowed value, so if you go with 1 table for posts and comments - you can define a foreign key to no-record by declaring the column as `comment_id_fk int default null`. However, you will still need to join the table onto itself to collect all comments that belong to a post so I don't see what you're gaining here except you have 1 table less to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These structures are quite different, and you do not provide enough information to answer the question.  Here are two important differences:

- The second structure allows comments on comments and for them to be nested.  The first requires that comments be on posts and posts are not nested.
- The second copies the `topic` into the comments.  This means that the topic on a comment can be different from the `topic` on the corresponding post.  This may be good or bad.  I am only pointing out that it is different.

These are important design considerations.  Your question doesn't provide enough information for an outsider to judge which is closer to your actual intentions.

As a *general* rule, I would be biased toward the first approach because I think of "posts" and "comments" as two different things, and hence worthy of being separate entities.  For instance, here at Stack Exchange, posts ("questions") have tags and comments do not, posts have titles and comments do not, and comments have a length limit that posts do not.

Comment: Great feedback! Would it be bad to add columns like tags and such to the comment table?

Comment: @Johan . . . That is a question about your application.  The `coments` table should what is necessary to support the application.